# Pyspark - configure Amazon Redshift JDBC jar

Tags: python, apache-spark, jdbc, jar, amazon-redshift

I am trying to use the `spark-redshift` databricks package and cannot get the `Redshift` `jdbc` driver working correctly. I have downloaded the latest version from [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html) and saved to an s3 bucket.

This is how I am launching the `spark-shell`

```
MASTER=yarn-client IPYTHON=1 PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python27 /usr/lib/spark/bin/pyspark 
--packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.10:2.0.1,com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.10:1.1.0 
--jars 's3://pathto/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar'
```

I am trying to read from Redshift as per the databricks readme

```
df = sql_context.read \
.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
.option("url", "jdbc:redshift://redshifthost:5439/database?user=username&password=pass") \
.option("dbtable", "my_table") \
.option("tempdir", "s3n://path/for/temp/data") \
.load()
```

but I get a configuration error:

```
 Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o46.load.
 : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load an Amazon Redshift JDBC driver; see the README for instructions on downloading and configuring the official Amazon driver.
```

The jar file seems to have been read so not sure how it needs to be specified differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just updating this as I realized what I was doing wrong. I was referencing the jar file in an s3 bucket but this needed to be available locally to the cluster.

```
aws s3 cp s3://pathto/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar /tmp/
```

Comment: I am also trying to do the same but getting dependency unresolved error, did you install any packages or made any config changes to run.